GGplot does not show all points on the x-axis
I have the following dataframe in which the x-axis represents the phases of a project (1 to 5 in ascending order) and the y-axis represents the names of the projects.
df1 = data.frame(a = c("Project1", "Project2", "Project3","Project4"),
    b = c(2, 4, 2, 5))

project 1 >>> phase 2
project 2 >>> phase 4
...
I want to plot a graph using ggplot that shows the x-axis with all the phases of the project according to the phases vector even if my dataframe does not have projects in phase 1 or 3, for example.
phases <- c("phase1", "phase2", "phase3", "phase4", "phase5")


The x-axis of the dataframe represents which phase the project is in at the moment. Therefore, project 1 is in phase 2, that is, it has passed through phase 1 and is now in phase 2. Project 2 is in phase 4 and has passed through phases 1, 2 and 3.
I would like the graph to highlight all the project phases for each project and a line or bar showing the phases it has passed and the current phase.


To avoid any doubt, consider that there is a possible phase 6 that I would like to be represented in the graph above even if my dataframe does not have any projects in this phase.

What ggplot plot code are you running? It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear how phases relates to your df1 data.

Also, it's hard to see your graph in dark mode, since it looks like you have a transparent instead of a white background.

You can use the scale_y_continuous() to set the labels on the axis.
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = c("Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4"),
  b = c(2, 4, 2, 5)
)

N <- 6

ggplot(df1, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Project", y = "Phase") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:N, labels = paste("phase", seq_len(N))) +
  expand_limits(y = N) +
  coord_flip()



The problem here is that if I have a phase 6 that is not present in my dataframe, it is not highlighted in the graph.

You can easily update it to any limit you want with "expand_limits(y = 6)".  I edit the answer accordingly
